# Better solution to do arbitrary assertions on an expected exception?

Tags: php, unit-testing, exception, phpunit

Doing arbitrary assertions on a thrown exception can be useful when it handles other information than a message or a code.

Is there a more simple, readable, or a more "phpunit-recommended way" to do that, than in the following example :

```
public function testTitleShouldNotAcceptArrayAsValue()
{
    /* Arrange */
    $schema = new sch\ObjectSchema();


    /* Expect */
    $this->expectException(sch\Exception::class);


    try {
        /* Act */
        $schema->title = [];
    } catch (sch\Exception $exception) {
        /* Assert */
        $this->assertEquals('title', $exception->getProperty());
        $this->assertEquals(
            [
                'properties' => [
                    'title' => [
                        'type' => 'string'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            $exception->getRules()
        );
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are putting additional information into the exception object, and want to prove in a test that it is being set, then I would use the try/catch as you have.

IMO, the `expectException()` and re-`throw` is redundant though. At the end of the catch I would just return out of the function with the pass, and after the catch block fail (with `$this->fail('sch\Exception was not thrown');`) as there was not an exception to catch, as was planned.

It would be completely obvious that it was doing - and clarity is more useful, much of the time, than elegance.